# Is JPARepository interface covers the responsibilities of DAO interface in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, dao

I'm new to Spring Boot and I have a question. I will present it as this.

DAO is a design pattern and It has three components. Those are

1. DAO interface - use to declare methods that need to perform on DTO
2. DAO interface implementation -use to take data from data source(database)
3. DTO(Data Transfer Object) - use to retain data to transport among layers.

For example, If we get Student.

**Student.java (DTO)**

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int rollNo;

    Student(String name, int rollNo) {
        this.name = name;
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

**StudentDao.java**

```
import java.util.List;

public interface StudentDao {
    public List<Student> getAllStudents();
    public Student getStudent(int rollNo);
    public void updateStudent(Student student);
    public void deleteStudent(Student student);
}
```

**StudentDaoImpl.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StudentDaoImpl implements StudentDao {

    //list is working as a database
    List<Student> students;

    public StudentDaoImpl(){
        students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        Student student1 = new Student("Robert",0);
        Student student2 = new Student("John",1);
        students.add(student1);
        students.add(student2);
    }
    @Override
    public void deleteStudent(Student student) {
        students.remove(student.getRollNo());
        System.out.println("Student: Roll No " + student.getRollNo() + ", deleted from database");
    }

    //retrive list of students from the database
    @Override
    public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    @Override
    public Student getStudent(int rollNo) {
        return students.get(rollNo);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateStudent(Student student) {
        students.get(student.getRollNo()).setName(student.getName());
        System.out.println("Student: Roll No " + student.getRollNo() + ", updated in the database");
    }
}
```

It is about the DAO. In spring boot, there is `JPARepository` interface. This interface has been declare the methods such as `save(), findById()`. and we can use the `JPARepository` as follows.

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Integer> {

}
```

Then after we can use this interface the `Controller` class.

**SoftwareEngineerController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "student")
public class SoftwareEngineerController {
    @Autowired
    StudentRepository studentRepository;

    //to retrieve all software engineers
    @GetMapping("/students")
    public List<Studentr> getAllEngineers(){
        return studentRepository.findAll();
}
```

I feel that the `JPARepository` interface and the `DAO` interface are doing the same task. (declare the essential methods are needed to perform to dealing with the data)Spring boot is containing the `JPARepository` hence no more need the DAO is inside the spring boot applications. Is it true?. I'm new to spring boot so if you can give me a good explanation I will highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are basically two design patterns. DAO Pattern and Repository Pattern.
So you don't need to use use them both. If you are using Repository pattern, much of heavy lifting is done by spring data jpa itself. Also lot of boilerplate code can be removed. 
In your example you can use repository pattern. Also In my opinion, it is better to use a service. Instead of directly calling repository from a controller, you can call the service (`SoftwareEngineerService`) and from service you can call a repository. So business logic will remain in service layer.

**Some more details about Repository vs DAO**

***Repository***:
It's a repository of a specific type of objects - it allows you to search for a specific type of objects as well as store them. Usually it will ONLY handle one type of objects. here in your example `Student`. You should not deal with other entities there.

A repository will most likely store all data in the same table, whereas the pattern doesn't require that. The fact that it only handles one type of data though, makes it logically connected to one main table (if used for DB persistence).

***DAO*** - data access object (in other words - object used to access data)
A DAO is a class that locates data for you (it is mostly a finder, but it's commonly used to also store the data). The pattern doesn't restrict you to store data of the same type, thus you can easily have a DAO that locates/stores related objects. You can have a DAO class to return diffrent type of objects wich are related but not same.

***Finally:*** Note that both patterns really mean the same (they store data and they abstract the access to it and they are both expressed closer to the domain model and hardly contain any DB reference), but the way they are used can be slightly different, DAO being a bit more flexible/generic, while Repository is a bit more specific and restrictive to a type only.